# my application crashes at KNearest::find_nearest

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to implement a OCR feature.

I have collected some samples and i want to use K-Nearest to implement it.

So, i use the below code to load data and initialize KNearest

```
KNearest knn = new KNearest;
Mat mData, mClass;
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
{
    Mat mImage = imread( FILENAME ); // the filename format is '%d.bmp', presenting a 15x15 image
    Mat mFloat;
    if (mImage.empty()) break; // if the file doesn't exist

    mImage.convertTo(mFloat, CV_32FC1);
    mData.push_back(mFloat.reshape(1, 1));
    mClass.push_back( '0' + i );
}

knn->train(mData, mClass);
```

Then, i call the code to find best result

```
for (vector<Mat>::iterator it = charset.begin(); it != charset.end(); ++it)
{
    Mat mFloat;
    it->convertTo(mFloat, CV_32FC1); // 'it' presents a 15x15 gray image
    float result = knn->find_nearest(mFloat.reshape(1, 1), knn->get_max_k());
}
```

But, my application crashes at find_nearest.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: try to understand if problem is find_nearest() or reshape(), for example calling only the second one inside for

Comment: @Velthune I think the problem is find_nearest() because i let them be a single call per line. reshape() seems work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to find the problem...

My sample image is a converted gray image by cvtColor, but my input image isn't.

After i add

```
cvtColor(mImage, mImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

between

```
if (mImage.empty()) break;
mImage.convertTo(mFloat, CV_32FC1);
```

find_nearest() return a value and my application is fine.